# where in the db is the "Automatic alias" setting stored for drupal's pathauto

Tags: drupal, pathauto

I created a bunch of nodes using `node_save()`. Unfortunately, I forgot to turn on the Automatic alias setting on them. Anyone know how I can do that now? I can't figure out where in the db that setting is stored. (Other non-db approaches are fine, too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer on drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/763874

The short version: that checkbox isn't stored in the db, it's calculated for the form. The reason my nodes didn't create aliases is that there's a limit on the number that can be created at a time (50 by default).

Answer (score 0):

In the path auto admin screen you can make a bulk alias creation operation. You can set the maximum alias' Per time created this way aswell.

I believe path alias also can be created in cron jobs, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But each node has to have its 'Automatic alias' checkbox checked on it's node/edit page in order for the bulk generation to affect the node. I'm trying to figure out where that checkbox is stored so I can set them all to "checked".